# CheckBoxes with QtreeWidget Pyside2

Tags: python, pipeline, pyside

im doing a GUI that list all references in scene in a QTreeWidget (this works well)
but i have 4 checkbox outside the QTreWidget that:

if i check (for example) "CHAR" box, only will be visible the characters
if i chechk (for example) "PROP" box, only will be visible the prop characters
and if a check "ALL" list all

i don have idea how will this work but i appreciate any help. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to filter results in the tree view or how to change the visibility of items in the scene?

Comment: i think visibility... because if a select the checkbox CHAR i want only was visible Char Items

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class main(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()


        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.tree = QTreeWidget()

        self.dict = {"item1":"Char", 
                    "item2":"Set", 
                    "item3":"Set", 
                    "item4":"Set", 
                    "item5":"Char", 
                    "item6":"Char", 
                    "item7":"char", 
                    "item8":"set", 
                    "item9":"Set", 
                    "item10":"Char"}

        self.item_list = []
        for i in self.dict:
            self.item = item(i, self.dict[i])
            self.item_list.append(self.item)

        self.tree.addTopLevelItems(self.item_list)

        self.check_list = []        
        self.check1 = check("All", self)
        self.check2 = check("Char", self)
        self.check3 = check("Set", self)

        self.vbox.addWidget(self.tree)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.check1)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.check2)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.check3)

        self.resize(700,500)
        self.show()

        self.selection = True


    def all_selection(self, check):
        if self.selection:
            self.selection = False

            for c in self.check_list:
                c.setChecked(check.isChecked())
            
            for i in range(self.tree.topLevelItemCount()):
                item = self.tree.topLevelItem(i)
                item.setHidden(not check.isChecked())
            
            self.selection = True

            
    def filter(self, check):
        if self.selection:
            self.selection = False

            for i in range(self.tree.topLevelItemCount()):
                item = self.tree.topLevelItem(i)
                
                for c in self.check_list:
                    if c.type in item.types:
                        item.setHidden(not c.isChecked())
                

                all_state = all([c.isChecked() for c in self.check_list[1:]])
                self.check_list[0].setChecked(all_state)
            
            self.selection = True



class check(QCheckBox):
    def __init__(self, text, parent):
        super().__init__(text)

        self.setChecked(True)
        parent.check_list.append(self)
        
        self.type = text.lower()
        self.parent = parent
        
        if self.type == "all":
            self.stateChanged.connect(lambda: self.parent.all_selection(self))
        else:
            self.stateChanged.connect(self.parent.filter)




class item(QTreeWidgetItem):
    def __init__(self, text, Type):
        super().__init__()

        self.setText(0, text)

        self.types = ["all", Type.lower()]



app = QApplication([])
window = main()
app.exec()
```